# Validating response xml based on condition in Karate

Tags: karate

My response xml from the karate api call is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <header>
      <node>
         <p n="CURRENCY">USD</p>
         <p n="REASON">This is a currency breach</p>
      </node>
   </header>
</response>
```

- string reason = 'This is currency breach'

I want to validate a use case --> if(true) match reposne contains reason

As I am having two type of messages based on a condition. How can I do if with match here.

Comment: Sorry Peter thomas, I have updated. I had tried to format it honestly, the site just gave it back. I have used another site and corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, and please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

```
* def response =
"""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <header>
      <node>
         <p n="CURRENCY">USD</p>
         <p n="REASON">This is a currency breach</p>
      </node>
   </header>
</response>
"""
* def condition = true
* def expected = condition ? 'This is a currency breach' : 'blah'
* match /response/header/node/p[@n='REASON'] == expected
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry about the early trouble with xml formatting.